# Create a method acting on different types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use different data types in a list. e.g:

```
data Shape = Square Int
            | Circle Int
            | Rectangle Int Int
            | Triangle Int Int Int
                 deriving (Show)


shapes = [Square 5, Circle 2, Rectangle 10 5]
showShapes :: [Shape] -> [Int]
showShapes [] = []
showShapes (s:xs) = getArea (s : xs)
```

However I'm struggling to create the method "getArea" as I need one for each different type. I don't know a way to do this using parameter pattern matching. Is there a way to do this or am I tackling this problem the wrong way?

### Edit

How would you do it using an if statement and "typeOf" function

I tried changing Shape to this:

```
data Shape = Square Int
            | Rectangle Int Int
            | Triangle Int Int Int
                 deriving (Show, Typeable)
```

But I get a compile time error!

Comment: "But I get a compile time error!" - What is that error?  It's pretty hard to diagnose the problem without knowing what's wrong!

Comment: You're not putting different data types in a list, here. You have only one data type: `Shape`. Shape has 4 different cases, and parameter pattern matching is exactly how you tell which case you have. Using `typeOf` wouldn't make sense here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your simple case, just use pattern matching in `getArea`, but you'll have to convert your values to Doubles since the area of a circle is never going to be an integer when you have an integer radius:

```
getArea :: Shape -> Double
getArea (Square l)       = fromIntegral $ l * l
getArea (Circle r)       = pi * fromIntegral r ^ 2
getArea (Rectangle l w)  = fromIntegral $ l * w
-- assuming the constructor takes the 3 side lengths
getArea (Triangle a b c) = sqrt $ p * (p - a') * (p - b') * (p - c')
    where
        [a', b', c'] = map fromIntegral [a, b, c]
        p = (a' + b' + c') / 2
```

Although I don't know what you want to do in `showShapes`.  Usually the word `show` in Haskell means the same thing as `toString` in other languages, but you're trying to apply `getArea` inside it.  Regardless, your pattern matching for `showShapes` is off, you need parentheses around `s:xs` or you'll get a syntax error, and you can't prepend a number on front of a list of `Shape`s as with `getArea s : xs`.  Instead you might be wanting to calculate the area for each shape in a list?  For that you can use `map`:

```
getAreas :: [Shape] -> [Double]
getAreas shapes = map getArea shapes
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Just an extension to the original question, how would you do it using an if statement and "typeOf" function. The function typeOf shapes didn't seem to work.

Comment: @YahyaUddin What is the type of `typeOf`?  This sounds like it's homework as well, what have you tried?  Please keep in mind that SO is not a forum for getting others to do your homework for you.

Comment: Thats not part of my home work lol. I 'll edit my post to show what I tried.

Comment: Beware: there's a typo in `getArea (Circle r)       = pi * fromIntegral r`.

Comment: @gallais Fixed, this is what happens when I write a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that you don't need to store all figures in one datatype in this case. You can use existential quantification instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Square    = Square Int
data Circle    = Circle Int
data Rectangle = Rectangle Int Int

class HasArea a where
    area :: a -> Double

instance HasArea Square where
    area (Square n) = fromIntegral n * fromIntegral n

instance HasArea Circle where
    area (Circle r) = pi * fromIntegral r ^ 2

instance HasArea Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle n m) = fromIntegral n * fromIntegral m

data Shape = forall s. HasArea s => Shape s

shapes :: [Shape]
shapes = [Shape (Square 5), Shape (Circle 2), Shape (Rectangle 10 5)]

shapeArea :: Shape -> Double
shapeArea (Shape s) = area s

main = print $ map shapeArea shapes
```

You can read about existential quantification here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types

Existential quantification itself is weaker, than generalized algebraic datatypes. You can read about them here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT

Comment: Actually, this is an antipattern: `[Shape]` does not convey more information than a `[Double]` since given a `Shape` the only thing you can do is computing its `area`. http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Comment: @chi I would say that the only real use of existentials here would be so that you can map `shapeArea` over the list instead of having to call `shapeArea` on each individual element of the list.  This could be useful for reducing typing and redundancy depending on the situation, but it's really only for creating an intermediate structure that is never used, only the result of mapping a function over it.  If I had 50 shapes in a list, this would make my life a lot easier and my code significantly more clear, but it wouldn't be any more useful than the `[Double]` is produces.

Comment: @chi, I disagree. First, the author of the post, you cited, says "it is really just a notational difference". Notational difference is not an antipattern. Second, `toWidget :: Window -> Widget` is actually `windowToWidget :: Window -> Widget`. `radio_buttonToWidget`, `combo_boxToWidget`... instead of just one `Widget`. Third, in more complex cases you would need a record anyway instead of nameless list of doubles. Why should you prefer something with precomputed (semantically precomputed, due to laziness) values? Obviously, you can equip your record with "methods", but why, when you have EQ?

Comment: To be honest, I do think that the "antipattern" has some value in some complex scenarios: Luke Palmer's post even shows a case in which you get less type information from the proposed simple representation than you would get with existential types and type classes (IIRC, moving a widget, which preserves type with TC and does not otherwise). In such cases, I disagree with calling ETs as an "antipattern". However, in this particular Shape/area example, existential types seem a bit overkill. I do understand it is a matter of personal preference at the end.

Comment: @chi, I agree, that it is overkill in this example. But that's just an example.